# How to move folder to a folder shared with me?

Tags: google-drive, google-account, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-folder

I have maintained a folder in Google Drive for an org I work with. Call the folder: \OrgDocs
-- There is a whole structure in here, including subfolders that are shared with individuals

The org itself now has a Google Drive account, and has shared a folder with me, called \TheOrg\

I am trying to move my \OrgDocs\ to a subfolder under \TheOrg\

But when I use the Move option in Google Drive, folder \TheOrg\ is not available to move it to.

I have confirmed that I have "Editor" permissions to folder \TheOrg\ and am out of ideas.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hello, have you checked if you have permissions to modify the destination folder?? If you have only view permissions, you won't be able to accomplish that

Comment: @Martín -- good point. I will check---YES, I have "Editor" permission to the destination folder (and I always did). OP enhanced. So now what?

Comment: Maybe try to access **\TheOrg\** from the desktop app, then upload the folder from your desktop to **\OrgDocs\** via the web app.

Comment: There are no "Google Drive accounts". There are Google accounts; a Google account might be a consumer / non-managed account or a managed account. Managed accounts are usually referred to as Google Apps, G Suite and Google Workspace accounts. Still, as the name of the service has changed over the years, and more recently the "Google Workspace" name is used for more things, the Google ecosystem has become more confusing. Please [edit] the question, first, to clarify the type of accounts used and the location of the folder.

Comment: By location of the folder, I'm referring to if the folder belongs to My Drive of one account or to another unit type, i.e. a mirrored / backed up Drive, or a Shared Drive. Please bear in mind that Google has replaced having files and folders in multiple locations by using file and folder shortcuts.